# Age of Empires 3 Update

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

Age of Empires 3 automatically updated and then I didn't need the CD. Is that meant to happen? Before it updated I tried it, and it needed the CD.

Comment: how long ago did you install it?

Comment: I think about 2 years ago

Comment: fwiw, I bought AOE3 on Steam and I do not need a CD. Anyways, It's quite possible that a patch was released which discontinued the need for a CD with AOE3. WarCraft 3 did this several years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Update 1.07 for Asian Dynasties removed the need for the CD. It was some years ago, but as far as I know it's still the most recent major update for the game.

It came along around the same time it was added to Steam.

Comment: Minor correction; the update version is 1.03, not 1.07. It was released in 2010 and indeed remains the most recent update.